# What's the type hint for "can be converted to" mean?

Tags: python, type-hinting

Let's say I want to accept anything I can call `int()` on, or anything I can call `str()` on. How do I do that with the new type hints ?

Annotating with `typing.SupportsInt` doesn't work, as mypy will warn against passing a string.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't, not with type hinting. Type hinting can't say anything about the *contents* of a string, only that it must *be* a string.

Note that *everything* in Python can be converted to a string (as `__repr__` is always available); so for 'can be converted to a string' can be handled by `typing.Any`.

For `int()`, you can only specify specific hooks and types again; you can specify you'll accept objects that have a [`__int__()`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__int__)  method, but if you also accept strings, you can't specify what is *in* that string.

So:

```
AcceptableToInt = Union[SupportsInt, str, bytes, bytearray]
```

would let you check on what types `int()` accepts, but not if they'll throw a `ValueError` exception when you actually try.

Comment: I don't want to know it's a valid value to be converted, only that the operation is allowed. In that sense, I want to allow a value that can cast a ValueError, but not a TypeError.

Comment: @e-satis: then just specify the types that `int()` accepts, so `Union[str, SupportsInt, ...]` type union.

Comment: So basically a mix between typing.SupportsInt and str and bool ?

Comment: Just tried it, it doesn't work for custom type just defining \_\_int\_\_. Duck typed class will not be considered a valid input, only the one explicitly subclassing SupportsInt

Comment: @e-satis that may well be a bug then.

Comment: @e-satis: tested again with an `issubclass()` check against the union, and that works just fine. If mypy doesn't accept instances of a class with `__int__` set for the `AcceptableToInt` `Union` in my answer, then that's a bug in that project.

Comment: Ok, I'll open a ticker on mypy, and accept your answer.

Comment: FYI, Guido officially stated structural typing was not in mypy yet, it's planned. So not a bug, just not implemented.

Comment: @e-satis: a missing feature, not a present bug :-)

Comment: `AcceptableToInt` is missing `SupportsIndex` and `SupportsTrunc` (cf. [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L199)). What a nightmare to type check integers!

Comment: I have opened a feature request here: https://github.com/python/typing/discussions/1098